# ¿Cómo ordenar las etiquetas de un código que genera una tabla de un dato buscado?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un sistema de búsqueda de datos en una base de datos, mediante similitud de caracteres.

Cuando el sistema consigue el dato, genera una tabla que muestra algunos campos. Quisiera agregarle a esa tabla dos botones de modificar y de eliminar, *cosa que ya tengo en otra lista.*

El problema que ocurre es que las etiquetas que maneja son de php, debido a que solo mostrará la tabla si consigue resultados (usando echo), había acomodado para que fuera html, pero aparecía una linea vacía con el botón de modificar y de eliminar automáticamente ya que no habían datos.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo podría hacer para que funcionaran ambos botones?

Este es el código:

```
    <?php
    include 'conexion.php';

    $q=$_POST['q'];
    $con=$m;
    $sql1="select * from alumno where cedu_alum LIKE '".$q."%' or   nom1_alum LIKE '".$q."%' or  nom2_alum LIKE '".$q."%' or ape1_alum LIKE '".$q."%' or  ape2_alum LIKE '".$q."%' LIMIT 0 , 5";
    $res=sql($sql1);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if($n==0){
    echo "<b>No se encontraron datos</b>";
    }
    else
    {
    $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>Primer Nombre</th>
    <th>Segundo Nombre </th>
    <th>Primer Apellido</th>
    <th>Segundo Apellido</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>';
    echo '<th>'.$fila['cedu_alum'].'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$fila['nom1_alum'].'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$fila['nom2_alum'].'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$fila['ape1_alum'].'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$fila['ape2_alum'].'</th>';
    echo '<th>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmSav();" href="modificar_alumno.php?proy_id=<?=$fila["cedu_alum"]?>">Modificar</a>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmDel();" href="borrar1.php?proy_id=<?=$fila["cedu_alum"]?>">Eliminar</a>';
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    }
    ?>
```

De esta manera se ve el codigo en la lista normal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y supondo deberia quedar algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En esta línea: `modificar_proyecto.php?proy_id=<?=$fila["proy_id"]?>Modificar` te hacen falta las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP: Así: `modificar_proyecto.php?proy_id=<?php $fila["proy_id"] ?>Modificar`

Comment: actualizada con el nuevo codigo

Comment: Creo que acabo de ver el problema y es algo realmente sencillo que poco o nada tiene que ver con lo que estábamos hablando. Por cierto, tal y como está ahora mismo el código, puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL, deberías corregir eso para evitar posibles ataques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas dos filas de código presentan el problema:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmSav();" href="modificar_alumno.php?proy_id=<?=$fila["cedu_alum"]?>">Modificar</a>';
echo '<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmDel();" href="borrar1.php?proy_id=<?=$fila["cedu_alum"]?>">Eliminar</a>';
```

y en concreto la parte en la que se escriben los datos por pantalla:

```
...proy_id=<?=$fila["cedu_alum"]?>"...
```

Ya estás en PHP, **no hace falta abrir/cerrar las llaves para mostrar los datos**, te basta con concatenarlos en la cadena usando el `.` (como ya estás haciendo con el resto de variables un poco más arriba):

```
...proy_id=' . $fila["cedu_alum . '"...
```

Con lo que el código de esas dos líneas quedaría así ya ya debería funcionar sin problemas:

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmSav();" href="modificar_alumno.php?proy_id=' . $fila["cedu_alum"] . '">Modificar</a>';
echo '<a class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmDel();" href="borrar1.php?proy_id=' . $fila["cedu_alum"] . '">Eliminar</a>';
```

Comment: que sencillo era, muchísimas gracias !, estoy con el interes de programar en android, como mostrabas tu aplicacion